# Getting a good grid layout in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a project in which I'm simulating (Conway's) Game Of Life in a simple software. The back-end part is finished but I'm having some troubles displaying the cells nicely. What I'm trying to achieve is having y rows and x columns (x and y may differ per simulation). Every cel can be either alive (some color) or dead (another color) and I'd like them to be squares or at least close to squares. I also need to be able modify a specific cell, for example the cell on row 5, column 3 may need to turn into a different color without affecting the other cells.

Because of these requirements I'm currently working with a GridBagLayout but I'm not getting the desired result. I'm facing two problems:

1. I'm only getting one row while I can modify how many columns I have
2. I have no idea how to make squares of each individual cell, they are sometimes stretched horizontally/vertically

My current code in which I'm fooling around until I get the right shape:

```
    //Set grid dimensions
    int gridSizeX = 5;
    int gridSizeY = 5;     
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;    

    //Set the frame
    f = new JFrame("Window");
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    //Set the panel
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);

    //Set the constraints
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 0.5;   

    //The panel that will hold the grid
    JPanel a;

    //Cycle through all fields of the grid and alternate between red and yellow fields
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSizeX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSizeY; j++)
        {
            a = new JPanel();
            if (i%2==0)
                a.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            else
                a.setBackground(Color.red);  
            c.gridx = i;
            c.gridy = j;
            p.add(a, c);
        }
    }

    //Make sure the frame and panel are shown
    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get more rows but the columns of the different rows are colored equally. You therefore don't see the difference. Use `(i+j)%2`
2. Besides `c.weightx = 0.5` you should also set `c.weighty = 0.5`

Comment: I feel so stupid about the first one! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for setting the color of each square is wrong. You can't just do a simple "i % 2". That only works for even rows. You need to flip the logic for odd rows.

So, you need an additional check to determine what row the square is being added to. So the logic would be something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            square.setBackground( (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.white );
        chessBoard.add( square );
    }
}
```

> I'm currently working with a GridBagLayout

Just use a `GridLayout`. No need to worry about constraints.

Comment: Alright, thank you for answering my silly question! I'll try it right away. ps. I like your way of coding.

Comment: @Vallas, so why are you not using the GridLayout. That is the proper layout manager for your requirement. It is easier to code and more efficient than using a GridBagLayout.

Comment: I'm a beginner when it comes to creating user interfaces and I am teaching myself. It felt more familiar since it's possible to modify a specific field (x,y) using a GridBagLayout, just like I'm used to in a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @Vallas, Why do you think you can't do that with a GridLayout. The whole point of a GridLayout is that is it based on rows/columns. When you use a GridBagLayout you could have 5 component is one row and 2 components in the other.

Comment: I was watching a video on Youtube where the person in the video stated that it wasn't possible to do that with a GridLayout and I was stupid enough to believe him (or misunderstood him, since I'm not a native english speaker). But that's really good to know, thank you!!